# The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to "Temperature" -JAVA

Tags: java

Goodday everybody,

So I made a class Temperature, which has a constructor to make the temperature. 
Temperature is an arraylist of 2 numbers [coldness, hotness].

```
    public int hotness;
public int coldness;
public int[] temperature;
public int maxTemperature = 10000;


//Constructor Temperature
public Temperature(int hotness, int coldness) {
    /**
     * A constructor for the Array Temperature
     */
    maxTemperature = getMaxTemperature();
        if(hotness <= maxTemperature && coldness <= maxTemperature)
        temperature[0] = coldness;
        temperature[1] = hotness;
        }
```

and now I want to go into another class and use that object Temperature to do some calculations. Here is the code for it.

```
    //Variabels

public int volatility;
private static Temperature temperature;
private static int intrensicExplosivity;

    public static int standardVolatility(){
    if(temperature[0] == 0){
        int standardVolatility = 100 * intrensicExplosivity * (0.10 * temperature[1]);
    }
```

so now I get the error: The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to "Temperature"

any solutions?

I'm quite new to Java, so it's probably just some synthax errors, but I just can't find it.

thanks in advance.
David

Comment: If there is an error, please post the stack trace of the exception or error please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
public static int standardVolatility() {
    if(temperature[0] == 0) {
```

try

```
public static int standardVolatility() {
    if(tepmerature.temperature[0] == 0) {
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Note that the `temperature` in your second snippet is of type `Temperature` which itself has an int-array called `temperature`. To access the `temperature`-array of the `Temperature` object, you'll have to do `temperature.temperature`.

---

As @Marko Topolnik points out, you may also want to change

```
public int[] temperature;
```

to

```
public int[] temperature = new int[2];
```

in order to make room for the two temperature values.

Comment: You can also advise him that he needs to init the array (that's his next error), or not use the array at all :)

Answer (score 1):

First create getter & setter methods into the Temperature class and then call temperature.getTempertature() and use it on the second class.

Comment: I changed the things you guys suggested, thank you everything works excellent now!! I would give more green V but can only one :p

Answer (score 0):

`tempeture` is of type `Tempeture` which is not an array. 
What you want is the array member `temperature` inside your object instance (which you also called `tempature`).

Anyway change line :

```
if(temperature[0] == 0) 
.
.
```

With :

```
if(temperature.tempature[0] == 0)
.
.
```

I would advise you to use getters and setters and also use name which wont confuse you.

Answer (score 0):

You mix up some variables here.

In your code block below, `temperature` refers to a instance of your `Temperature` class, but you assumed it refers to the temperature array, which is a member of the `Temperature` class.

```
public static int standardVolatility() {
    if(temperature.temperature[0] == 0){
        int standardVolatility = 100 * intrensicExplosivity * (0.10 * temperature[1]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, your problem is here

```
private static Temperature temperature;
if(temperature[0] == 0){
        int standardVolatility = 100 * intrensicExplosivity * (0.10 * temperature[1]);
}
```

You are using an object as an array . That's wrong.
Instead, use a GET and set method from which you set and get the temperature .
Don't make all your data public , that's very bad for OO Programming. Use those getters and setters.
Somthing like: `if(temperature.getTemperature()==0)  etc.`

PS: Don't forget to intialize objects with new operator ( `Temperature temperature = new Temperature(10,30);` )